# How do I paste one part of a 2D Array in VBA?

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

If I have an 2D array as such:

```
        myArray(0, 0) = 69
        myArray(1, 0) = 69
        myArray(0, 1) = 1234
        myArray(0, 1) = 12345
```

Is there a way to paste only myArray( , 1) into Range("A1:A2") without using loops? I know you can paste like

> Range("A1:B2") = myArray

super easily.

I'll be having over 170,000 array columns so I prefer not using loops as it would take me over 35 minutes each time
I prefer keeping the dimensions and not changing the 2D array into two 1D arrays and pasting like that.

Comment: the example you gave above is a value assignment. it is not pasting.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant. My b

Comment: Suppose the last array row in your example should be indexed `myArray(1, 1) = 12345`. (Note: I added a third array row in my answer just to point out the proceding to extract a column from a 3x2 instead of 2x2 array; so you have to write to A1:A3 instead of A1:A2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method**

You can use `Application.Index` to get the column values out of your array and write them back to range.

**Code**

```
Sub testArCol2Row()
Dim myArray(0 To 2, 0 To 1)
Dim ws   As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MySheet")
Dim j As Long           ' Column number -- ONE BASED !!
j = 2                   ' <<<    change column number here
' example data
  myArray(0, 0) = 69
  myArray(1, 0) = 70
  myArray(2, 0) = 71
  myArray(0, 1) = 1234
  myArray(1, 1) = 12345
  myArray(2, 1) = 123456
' a) write both columns to range (just to compare values)
  ws.Range("E1:F3") = myArray
' get 2nd column into Array
  v = Application.Index(myArray, , j)
' b) write ONLY 2nd column (j=2) to range (column number -- ONE based if using index function)
  ws.Range("A1:A3") = v
End Sub
```

**Hint**

You can change the row - column order using `Application.Transpose`